# How to get 2 averages in the same row in CSVPython

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to get this end result

```
Please enter a training file name: train.csv

Total Lines Processed: 303

Total Healthy Count: 164

Total Ill Count: 139

Averages of Healthy Patients:

[52.59, 0.56, 2.79, 129.25, 242.64, 0.14, 0.84, 158.38, 0.14, 0.59, 1.41, 0.27, 3.77, 0.00]
Averages of Ill Patients:

[56.63, 0.82, 3.59, 134.57, 251.47, 0.16, 1.17, 139.26, 0.55, 1.57, 1.83, 1.13, 5.80, 2.04]
Seperation Values are:

[54.61, 0.69, 3.19, 131.91, 247.06, 0.15, 1.00, 148.82, 0.34, 1.08, 1.62, 0.70, 4.79, 1.02]
```

So far this is what I have in my code. I'm currently don't know how to get the averages of the healthy patients and ill patients. Any help on how to proceed is appreciated.

```
import csv
#turn csv files into a list of lists
with open('train.csv') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     csv_data = list(reader)


#count the amount of patients with heart problems
Icount = 0
Hcount = 0
for row in csv_data:
    try:
        if (row and int(row[13]) > 0):
            Icount += 1
        if (row and int(row[13]) <=0):
            Hcount += 1
    except IndexError:
        print("could not find the heart diseases status for the row" + str(row))
file = open("train.csv")
numline = len(file.readlines())
HPavg = ( )/(Hcount)
IPavg = ( )/(Icount)

print(numline)
print("Total amount of healthy patients " + str(Icount))
print("Total amount of ill patients " + str(Hcount))
print("Averages of healthy patients " + str(HPavg))
print("Averages of ill patients " + str(IPavg))
```

Comment: @ritesht93 ty that looks a lot better.

Comment: On a side note I assume that I would have to use the split function to be able to get to the step to get the average am I on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking to sum up the values of ill (and healthy) patients.

So here's how you can address ill patients (same pattern would apply to healthy). Instead of `Icount += 1` consider appending the value to a list, e.g.

```
i_list = []
for row in csv_data:
    if row and int(row[13]) > 0:
        i_list.append(int(row[13]))
    ...

Icount = len(i_list)
IPavg = sum(i_list)/Icount
```

Comment: Ok wow hahaha I feel dumb I read over that in my notes like 20 minutes ago and just passed by it. Thanks man I really appreciate it.

Comment: Use 2 lists and append to the appropriate list based on your if conditions.